# How to make this scroll to div script "smooth"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I found this script by a user of this site however I can't remember the author. The script is working, however I want it to scroll more "smoothly" than just instantly appear at my desired information. And if possible, have the destination appear 300pixels above the div.

How do I do that?

```css
#general{
  margin-top:900px; 
  height: 100px;
  weight:  100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var hashTagActive = "";
$(".scroll").click(function (event) {
    if(hashTagActive != this.hash) { //this will prevent if the user click several times the same link to freeze the scroll.
        event.preventDefault();
        //calculate destination place
        var dest = 0;
        if ($(this.hash).offset().center > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
        } else {
            dest = $(this.hash).offset().center;
        }
        //go to destination
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: dest
        }, 2000, 'swing');
        hashTagActive = this.hash;
    }
});
</script>
<div>
<a class="scroll" href="#general">Hello</a>
</div>
<div id="general">
</div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to animate to `#id` links:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rblakeley/Lbejdwy4/5/)

#### HTML

```
<a href="#content">Click me!</a><br>
<a href="google.com">Google.com</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
#content {
    margin-top: 900px; 
    height: 100px; width: 100px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    var target = $(this.hash),
        top;

    if (target) {
        top = target.offset().top;

        event.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: top
        }, 600, 'swing');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying your code and it works in jsfiddle but when I try to include it in my html it doesn't work. It works in jsfiddle but not when I make a html, its like there is no script. I tested another script to see if jquery was propely imported and it succeded, so it's not that I think. [My page](http://fransbergstrom.kaggteknik.se/Test/)

Comment: When I clicked your link, I got "webpage not available". Maybe paste your .html example? [`console.log`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) is a good method to test which blocks of javascript are executing.

Answer (score 1):

For a smoother scroll you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ANCHOR LINK").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 1000);
  });
});
```

And you see the last number? `1000`, make it bigger to make it slower.

The second thing I'm afraid I can't help you with.

Answer (score 0):

For smooth scroll to 300px above top of the element, your JavaScript function should look like this :

```
$(".scroll").click(function (event) {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(this.hash).offset().top - 300)
    }, 2000);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```